# Does a worn down battery charge faster than a new battery

Tags: laptop, battery

My laptop which is from late 2012 has a worn down battery which only lasts for 15 minutes.For some reason it charges from 15% to 100% in 1 hour of active web browsing and coding. But my Nexus 9 tablet which has a healthy battery takes 3 hours to charge from 15% to 100% without using it. If I try to use my Nexus 9 while charging it says 12 hours to charge.

Do worn down batteries charge faster than new ones?

Comment: If it lasts only 15 minutes, it isn't holding much energy.  It doesn't take as long to store a small fraction of the energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given the following:

A worn down battery reduces the overall capacity. If you have 25% wear, your actual overall capacity is 75% of the original. If the battery requires four hours to charge from 0%-100%, you would reach "100%" in three hours. This is because the maximum available is reported, not the original capacity.